# how to get a string to read out a consecutive numbers into and if statement?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

Out of my center variable I have the values 63.00000000000006,37,127 as strings

How do I convert them to numbers and then run them through my if statement?

```
    var curr = l.getvalue(); //get the current value

    var x;
    var amnt = x; // variation around center


    var center = mainval.toString().slice(',');



    post(center);

    //post('center ' + center);

    if (curr < center){
        val = center + ((Math.random() * 10) + amnt);
        l.setvalue(val);
        //this calculation if curr is less than center
    }


    else if (curr >= center){
        val = center + ((Math.random() * 10) - amnt);
        l.setvalue(val);
        //this calculation if curr is more than center
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is `.slice(',')`? did you mean `.split(',')` - if so, then you'd `.split(',').map(Number)` - but then `center` would be an array, so the rest of the code makes no sense - what is the value of `mainval`?

Comment: it's strange, if I do that I get what looks like number but running `typeof center` tells me they're objects - also they still don't trigger the if statement

Comment: typeof center is an object (actually an array) ... the contents of the array are numbers - and of course they don't work with the if statement... because you can't compare an array to a number - you'll need a loop ... but then, the code you've shown, there's no need for a loop, because the result will be whatever the last iteration does ... all in all, the code you've presented doesn't show enough for what you actually want to do with these three values of center

Comment: ok, so then I need some more code to split the numbers out of the array to trigger the `if` statement?

Comment: no idea dude ... your code shows comparison of one value, but you have three ... describe the logic of having 3 centres to compare with